# I do a AB Apache Test and it seems good, But when I load my website I get Errors

Tags: performance, wordpress, ab

I have an online shopping website, I use WordPress, WooCommerce and W3 Total Cache.

I do a AB:

```
    ab -l -r -n 600 -c 30 -k -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
```

And I get the following results:

```
    Server Software:        LiteSpeed
    Server Hostname:        *******************
    Server Port:            80

    Document Path:          /
    Document Length:        Variable

    Concurrency Level:      30
    Time taken for tests:   31.311 seconds
    Complete requests:      600
    Failed requests:        0
    Keep-Alive requests:    0
    Total transferred:      6349627 bytes
    HTML transferred:       6210786 bytes
    Requests per second:    19.16 [#/sec] (mean)
    Time per request:       1565.550 [ms] (mean)
    Time per request:       52.185 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
    Transfer rate:          198.04 [Kbytes/sec] received

    Connection Times (ms)
                  min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
    Connect:      167  389 272.8    346    3408
    Processing:   234 1057 1371.0    442   12508
    Waiting:      195  495 482.7    386    4968
    Total:        405 1446 1394.5    851   12808

    Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
      50%    851
      66%    992
      75%   1664
      80%   2421
      90%   3442
      95%   4078
      98%   6122
      99%   6766
     100%  12808 (longest request)
```

It seems ok, but the problem is that **20/30 times a day** I get a **Request Timeout** error, sometimes I get other errors.
I contact the Hosting and they always say it's ok. I'm confused.
All I ask is... Is something wrong with my test???
Thanks...